# How to specify email address in Flow using email alert/template

Tags: visual-workflow, email-alert

I want to use an email template when I send an email via a flow.  I am sending the email to users who are following a custom object's record.  The email is successfully sending when I use the flow's simpleemail feature.  I am not sure how to specify what email I want the template to go to when using an email alert.  Is what I am trying to do possible?  I feel that I should specify the project record's id in the input field for the email action because I need to display information about the project record in the body of the email.

Comment: so you are trying to send an email to the Chatter followers of some custom object? Where are they supposed to appear: in the To:, cc:, or bcc: address field?

Comment: My Community users can select Follow on records of a custom object.  When I choose to run the flow and specify the custom object record that I want the followers notified about, I want to send a nice-looking email (template) to the followers with details about the record they are following.  To do this, I need to somehow indicate who I want the alert to go to.  Hopefully I am explaining the scenario.

Comment: presumably they should be on bcc list so one community user is unaware of the other's email address and you can avoid "reply all"

Comment: I want to send individual emails to the community members who are following a particular record.  How do I get the community member's email to be used when sending an email alert?  I don't want to send the message to all Community members.

Comment: That would then require a loop through the recipients to send it individually to each (instead of using bcc). Also, if you are using an email alert notice the recipients are not dynamic enough to pass a follower list at the time of sending the email.

Comment: I am looping through and can send the simple emails to the individuals who are following the records.  Are you saying that I cannot use flow to send template emails to the individuals through the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED 11/12/2019 1:17pm PST

To solve this usecase, query the `EntitySubscription` Object to gather the users who should receive the email and leverage the Flow Core Action: Send email (instead of the Simple Email)

Addition by Kleinhomer 11/13/19 3:45 PM EST:  Because the custom object that I made the email template off of didn't have an email address associated with it to indicate who I wanted to send the email to (record's follower), I added an email address field to the custom object.  When I looped through the followers of the custom object's record, I temporarily updated the email field on the record while in the loop.  This allowed me to send the email template to each individual follower.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_actions_sendemail.htm&language=en_us&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5

**Option #2**
Use invokable apex to send the email. The flow should pass the template name and  the collection of users and apex would fire the `sendEmail()` function from the `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` class.

.

Comment: That is an idea.  I am first going to see if I can call a PB process from a Flow and pass it the parameters that will be needed to correctly send the email.

Comment: Flow can query EntitySubscription where ParentId = targetObjId  - this would avoid invocable apex

Comment: The invokable apex is to set the recipients in the SingleEmail as email alert would not offer this possibility

Comment: Ah, right, Flow's Core Action `Send an Email` supports text templates but not Email Templates but otherwise, the core action can be used to send email to a specific recipient

Comment: @cropredy Do you know how to easily leverage templates using Flow's Core Action `Send an Email`? This might be the limitation that would make apex more attractive.

Comment: sadly - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_actions_sendemail.htm&type=5 - Flow text templates can be formatted but they are not `Email Templates` _per se_. In effect, OP would be encapsulating "email template" inside flow and changes therein would require flow updates